# Can we have multiple directories for core.hooksPath?

Tags: git, hook

It seems that if I setup `core.hooksPath` in the global config file `~/.gitconfig`, the hooks inside `$GIT_DIR/hooks` will no be executed.

Can we have hooks in these two folders running at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You need to choose one of them or neither. These folders may have hooks with the same name. If both take effect, which should be invoked?

In your case, by default, the hooks defined by the global `core.hooksPath` are to be invoked.

To invoke those in `$GIT_DIR/hooks`,

```
# for permanent
# the local config has higher precedence than the global config
git config core.hooksPath $(git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir)/hooks
git some_command

# for once
git -c core.hooksPath=.git/hooks some_command
```

To invoke neither,

```
# for permanent
git config core.hooksPath <some_path_without_hooks>
git some_command

# for once
git -c core.hooksPath=<some_path_without_hooks> some_command
```